# open cv error(fatal signal 11) if images converted to grayscale

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I know its related to heap of device but it even crashes when i use very small images.And i tried it on samsung grand,motog,karbonn titanium s1.It crashes everywhere>is there a way to handle it.The only thing iam doing is first converting the images to gray scale and then compare.if i compare images without converting to grayscale it works fine no matter how big is image.
here is my code--

main activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private static final String TAG = "OCVSample::Activity";
        private static Bitmap bmp, yourSelectedImage, bmpimg1, bmpimg2;
        private static ImageView iv1, iv2;
        private static TextView tv;
        private static String path1, path2;
        private static String text;
        private static Button start;
        private static int imgNo = 0;
        private static Uri selectedImage;
        private static InputStream imageStream;
        private static long startTime, endTime;
        private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 100;

        //private static int descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.BRISK;
        private static int descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.SIFT;
        private static String descriptorType;
        private static int min_dist = 10;
        private static int min_matches = 750;

        public MainActivity() {
            Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
        }

        private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
            @Override
            public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
                switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                    doTask1(iv1,true);
                    doTask1(iv2, false);
                }
                    break;
                default: {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                }
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            iv1 = (ImageView) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.img1);
            iv2 = (ImageView) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.img2);
            start = (Button) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            tv = (TextView) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_4, this,
                    mLoaderCallback);


            run();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_settings:
                Intent call = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Settings.class);
                call.putExtra("descriptor", descriptor);
                call.putExtra("min_dist", min_dist);
                call.putExtra("min_matches", min_matches);
                call.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                call.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                startActivity(call);
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (descriptor == DescriptorExtractor.BRIEF)
                descriptorType = "BRIEF";
            else if (descriptor == DescriptorExtractor.BRISK)
                descriptorType = "BRISK";
            else if (descriptor == DescriptorExtractor.FREAK)
                descriptorType = "FREAK";
            else if (descriptor == DescriptorExtractor.ORB)
                descriptorType = "ORB";
            else if (descriptor == DescriptorExtractor.SIFT)
                descriptorType = "SIFT";
            else if(descriptor == DescriptorExtractor.SURF)
                descriptorType = "SURF";
            System.out.println(descriptorType);
            tv.setText("Select the two images to be compared.\n"+"DescriptorExtractor:"+descriptorType+"\nHamming distance between descriptors:"+min_dist+"\nMinimum number of good matches:"+min_matches);
            iv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
                    imgNo = 1;

                }
            });
            iv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
                    imgNo = 2;
                }
            });
            start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (bmpimg1 != null && bmpimg2 != null) {
                        /*if(bmpimg1.getWidth()!=bmpimg2.getWidth()){
                            bmpimg2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmpimg2, bmpimg1.getWidth(), bmpimg1.getHeight(), true);
                        }*/
                        bmpimg1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmpimg1, 100, 100, true);
                        bmpimg2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmpimg2, 100, 100, true);
                        Mat img1 = new Mat();
                        Utils.bitmapToMat(bmpimg1, img1);
                        Mat img2 = new Mat();
                        Utils.bitmapToMat(bmpimg2, img2);
                        Imgproc.cvtColor(img1, img1, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY); 
                        Imgproc.cvtColor(img2, img2, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY); 
                        img1.convertTo(img1, CvType.CV_32F);
                        img2.convertTo(img2, CvType.CV_32F);
                        //Log.d("ImageComparator", "img1:"+img1.rows()+"x"+img1.cols()+" img2:"+img2.rows()+"x"+img2.cols());
                        Mat hist1 = new Mat();
                        Mat hist2 = new Mat();
                        MatOfInt histSize = new MatOfInt(180);
                        MatOfInt channels = new MatOfInt(0);
                        ArrayList<Mat> bgr_planes1= new ArrayList<Mat>();
                        ArrayList<Mat> bgr_planes2= new ArrayList<Mat>();
                        Core.split(img1, bgr_planes1);
                        Core.split(img2, bgr_planes2);
                        MatOfFloat histRanges = new MatOfFloat (0f, 180f);              
                        boolean accumulate = false;
                        Imgproc.calcHist(bgr_planes1, channels, new Mat(), hist1, histSize, histRanges, accumulate);
                        Core.normalize(hist1, hist1, 0, hist1.rows(), Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());
                        Imgproc.calcHist(bgr_planes2, channels, new Mat(), hist2, histSize, histRanges, accumulate);
                        Core.normalize(hist2, hist2, 0, hist2.rows(), Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());
                            img1.convertTo(img1, CvType.CV_32F);
                            img2.convertTo(img2, CvType.CV_32F);
                            hist1.convertTo(hist1, CvType.CV_32F);
                            hist2.convertTo(hist2, CvType.CV_32F);

                            double compare = Imgproc.compareHist(hist1, hist2, Imgproc.CV_COMP_CHISQR);
                            Log.v("ImageComparator", "compare: "+compare);
                            if(compare>0 && compare<1500) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Images may be possible duplicates, verifying", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                new asyncTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
                            }
                            else if(compare==0)
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Images are exact duplicates", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Images are not duplicates", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "You haven't selected images.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onNewIntent(Intent newIntent) {
            super.onNewIntent(newIntent);
            min_dist = newIntent.getExtras().getInt("min_dist");
            descriptor = newIntent.getExtras().getInt("descriptor");
            min_matches = newIntent.getExtras().getInt("min_matches");
            run();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

            switch (requestCode) {
            case SELECT_PHOTO:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    try{
                    selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    try {
                        imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                                selectedImage);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    if (imgNo == 1) {
                        iv1.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                        path1 = selectedImage.getPath();
                        bmpimg1 = yourSelectedImage;
                        iv1.invalidate();
                    } else if (imgNo == 2) {
                        iv2.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                        path2 = selectedImage.getPath();
                        bmpimg2 = yourSelectedImage;
                        iv2.invalidate();
                    }
                    }
                    catch(OutOfMemoryError exception){
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), exception.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Image cant be selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_4, this,   // My changes
                    mLoaderCallback);
        }

        public static class asyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            private static Mat img1, img2, descriptors, dupDescriptors;
            private static FeatureDetector detector;
            private static DescriptorExtractor DescExtractor;
            private static DescriptorMatcher matcher;
            private static MatOfKeyPoint keypoints, dupKeypoints;
            private static MatOfDMatch matches, matches_final_mat;
            private static ProgressDialog pd;
            private static boolean isDuplicate = false;
            private MainActivity asyncTaskContext=null;
            private static Scalar RED = new Scalar(255,0,0);
            private static Scalar GREEN = new Scalar(0,255,0);
            public asyncTask(MainActivity context)
            {
                asyncTaskContext=context;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                pd = new ProgressDialog(asyncTaskContext);
                pd.setIndeterminate(true);
                pd.setCancelable(true);
                pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                pd.setMessage("Processing...");
                pd.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                compare();
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                try {
                    Mat img3 = new Mat();
                    MatOfByte drawnMatches = new MatOfByte();
                    Features2d.drawMatches(img1, keypoints, img2, dupKeypoints,
                            matches_final_mat, img3, GREEN, RED,  drawnMatches, Features2d.NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);
                    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(img3.cols(), img3.rows(),
                            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Imgproc.cvtColor(img3, img3, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);
                    Utils.matToBitmap(img3, bmp);
                    List<DMatch> finalMatchesList = matches_final_mat.toList();
                    final int matchesFound=finalMatchesList.size();
                    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    if (finalMatchesList.size() > min_matches)// dev discretion for
                                                            // number of matches to
                                                            // be found for an image
                                                            // to be judged as
                                                            // duplicate
                    {
                        text = finalMatchesList.size()
                                + " matches were found. Possible duplicate image.\nTime taken="
                                + (endTime - startTime) + "ms";
                        isDuplicate = true;
                    } else {
                        text = finalMatchesList.size()
                                + " matches were found. Images aren't similar.\nTime taken="
                                + (endTime - startTime) + "ms";
                        isDuplicate = false;
                    }
                    pd.dismiss();
                    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            asyncTaskContext);
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Result");
                    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(asyncTaskContext);
                    final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.image_view, null);
                    ImageView matchedImages = (ImageView) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.finalImage);
                    matchedImages.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    matchedImages.invalidate();
                    final CheckBox shouldBeDuplicate = (CheckBox) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
                    TextView message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);
                    message.setText(text);
                    alertDialog.setView(view);
                    shouldBeDuplicate
                            .setText("These images are actually duplicates.");
                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Add to logs",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    File logs = new File(Environment
                                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                            .getAbsolutePath()
                                            + "/imageComparator/Data Logs.txt");
                                    FileWriter fw;
                                    BufferedWriter bw;
                                    try {
                                        fw = new FileWriter(logs, true);
                                        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                                        bw.write("Algorithm used: "
                                                + descriptorType
                                                + "\nHamming distance: "
                                                + min_dist + "\nMinimum good matches: "+min_matches
                                                +"\nMatches found: "+matchesFound+"\nTime elapsed: "+(endTime-startTime)+"seconds\n"+ path1
                                                + " was compared to " + path2
                                                + "\n" + "Is actual duplicate: "
                                                + shouldBeDuplicate.isChecked()
                                                + "\nRecognized as duplicate: "
                                                + isDuplicate + "\n");
                                        bw.close();
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                asyncTaskContext,
                                                "Logs updated.\nLog location: "
                                                        + Environment
                                                                .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                                                .getAbsolutePath()
                                                        + "/imageComparator/Data Logs.txt",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        // e.printStackTrace();
                                        try {
                                            File dir = new File(Environment
                                                    .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                                    .getAbsolutePath()
                                                    + "/imageComparator/");
                                            dir.mkdirs();
                                            logs.createNewFile();
                                            logs = new File(
                                                    Environment
                                                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                                            .getAbsolutePath()
                                                            + "/imageComparator/Data Logs.txt");
                                            fw = new FileWriter(logs, true);
                                            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                                            bw.write("Algorithm used: "
                                                    + descriptorType
                                                    + "\nMinimum distance between keypoints: "
                                                    + min_dist + "\n" + path1
                                                    + " was compared to " + path2
                                                    + "\n"
                                                    + "Is actual duplicate: "
                                                    + shouldBeDuplicate.isChecked()
                                                    + "\nRecognized as duplicate: "
                                                    + isDuplicate + "\n");
                                            bw.close();
                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                    asyncTaskContext,
                                                    "Logs updated.\nLog location: "
                                                            + Environment
                                                                    .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                                                    .getAbsolutePath()
                                                            + "/imageComparator/Data Logs.txt",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e1.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(asyncTaskContext, e.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            void compare() {
                try {
                    bmpimg1 = bmpimg1.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                    bmpimg2 = bmpimg2.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                    img1 = new Mat();
                    img2 = new Mat();
                    Utils.bitmapToMat(bmpimg1, img1);
                    Utils.bitmapToMat(bmpimg2, img2);
                    Imgproc.cvtColor(img1, img1, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);
                    Imgproc.cvtColor(img2, img2, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);
                    detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.PYRAMID_FAST);
                    DescExtractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(descriptor);
                    matcher = DescriptorMatcher
                            .create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);

                    keypoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
                    dupKeypoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
                    descriptors = new Mat();
                    dupDescriptors = new Mat();
                    matches = new MatOfDMatch();
                    detector.detect(img1, keypoints);
                    Log.d("LOG!", "number of query Keypoints= " + keypoints.size());
                    detector.detect(img2, dupKeypoints);
                    Log.d("LOG!", "number of dup Keypoints= " + dupKeypoints.size());
                    // Descript keypoints
                    DescExtractor.compute(img1, keypoints, descriptors);
                    DescExtractor.compute(img2, dupKeypoints, dupDescriptors);
                    Log.d("LOG!", "number of descriptors= " + descriptors.size());
                    Log.d("LOG!",
                            "number of dupDescriptors= " + dupDescriptors.size());
                    // matching descriptors
                    matcher.match(descriptors, dupDescriptors, matches);
                    Log.d("LOG!", "Matches Size " + matches.size());
                    // New method of finding best matches
                    List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList();
                    List<DMatch> matches_final = new ArrayList<DMatch>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < matchesList.size(); i++) {
                        if (matchesList.get(i).distance <= min_dist) {
                            matches_final.add(matches.toList().get(i));
                        }
                    }

                    matches_final_mat = new MatOfDMatch();
                    matches_final_mat.fromList(matches_final);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }


        public void doTask1(ImageView iv,boolean iv_flag) {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            if(iv_flag){
                   bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.download);
            }
            else{
                   bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "bitmap: " + bitmap.getWidth() + "x" + bitmap.getHeight());


            bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            Log.d(TAG, "bitmap 8888: " + bitmap.getWidth() + "x" + bitmap.getHeight());


            //GrabCut part
            Mat img = new Mat();
            Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, img);
            Log.d(TAG, "img: " + img);

            int r = img.rows();
            int c = img.cols();
            Point p1 = new Point(c/10, r/10);
            Point p2 = new Point(c-c/10, r-r/10);
            Rect rect = new Rect(p1, p2);
            Log.d(TAG, "rect: " + rect);

            Mat mask = new Mat();
            Mat fgdModel = new Mat();
            Mat bgdModel = new Mat();


            Mat imgC3 = new Mat();
            Imgproc.cvtColor(img, imgC3, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);
            Log.d(TAG, "imgC3: " + imgC3);

            Log.d(TAG, "Grabcut begins");
            Imgproc.grabCut(imgC3, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 2, Imgproc.
            GC_INIT_WITH_RECT);
            Log.d(TAG, "Grabcut ends");

            Log.d(TAG, "mask: " + mask);
            Log.d(TAG, "bgdModel: " + bgdModel);
            Log.d(TAG, "fgdModel: " + fgdModel);

            Core.convertScaleAbs(mask, mask, 100, 0);
            Imgproc.cvtColor(mask, mask, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA);
            Log.d(TAG, "maskC4: " + mask);

            //convert to Bitmap
            Log.d(TAG, "Convert to Bitmap");
            //Utils.matToBitmap(imgC3, bitmap);
            Utils.matToBitmap(mask, bitmap);
            iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            if(iv_flag)
            bmpimg1=bitmap;
            else
                bmpimg2=bitmap;
            //release MAT part
            img.release();
            imgC3.release();
            mask.release();
            fgdModel.release();
            bgdModel.release();
            }
    }



settings activity---

public class Settings extends Activity {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static RadioGroup descTypes;
    private static RadioButton brief, brisk, freak, orb;
    private static Button apply;
    private static EditText DIST_LIMIT, MIN_MATCHES;
    private static int descriptor, min_dist, min_matches;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        descTypes = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        brief = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        brisk = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        freak = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        orb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);
        apply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        DIST_LIMIT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        MIN_MATCHES = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        MIN_MATCHES.setText("100");
        DIST_LIMIT.setText("80");
        apply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int descriptor = 0, min_dist = 80, min_matches=100;
                if (brief.isChecked())
                    descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.BRIEF;
                else if (brisk.isChecked())
                    descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.BRISK;
                else if (freak.isChecked())
                    descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.FREAK;
                else if (orb.isChecked())
                    descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.ORB;
                try {
                    min_dist = Integer.parseInt(DIST_LIMIT.getText().toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    min_dist = 500;
                }
                Intent call = new Intent(Settings.this, MainActivity.class);
                call.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                call.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                call.putExtra("descriptor", descriptor);
                call.putExtra("min_dist", min_dist);
                call.putExtra("min_matches", min_matches);
                startActivity(call);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent newIntent) {
        super.onNewIntent(newIntent);
        descriptor = newIntent.getExtras().getInt("descriptor");
        min_dist = newIntent.getExtras().getInt("min_dist");
        min_matches = newIntent.getExtras().getInt("min_matches");
        DIST_LIMIT.setText(min_dist + "");
        switch (descriptor) {
        case 3:
            orb.setChecked(true);
            break;
        case 4:
            brief.setChecked(true);
            break;
        case 5:
            brisk.setChecked(true);
            break;
        case 6:
            freak.setChecked(true);
            break;
        }
        apply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (brief.isChecked())
                    descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.BRIEF;
                else if (brisk.isChecked())
                    descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.BRISK;
                else if (freak.isChecked())
                    descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.FREAK;
                else if (orb.isChecked())
                    descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.ORB;
                try {
                    min_dist = Integer.parseInt(DIST_LIMIT.getText().toString());
                    min_matches = Integer.parseInt(MIN_MATCHES.getText().toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    min_dist = 80;
                    min_matches=100;
                }
                Intent call = new Intent(Settings.this, MainActivity.class);
                call.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                call.putExtra("descriptor", descriptor);
                call.putExtra("min_dist", min_dist);
                call.putExtra("min_matches", min_matches);
                startActivity(call);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

and the logcat---

```
08-22 18:44:11.919: V/ImageComparator(24384): compare: 48.32461247119096
08-22 18:44:12.139: D/LOG!(24384): number of query Keypoints= 1x65
08-22 18:44:12.139: D/LOG!(24384): number of dup Keypoints= 1x62
08-22 18:44:12.139: A/libc(24384): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 24587 (AsyncTask #1)
```

Comment: It's like a null pointer exception from NDK. Could be an unallocated array or an index out-of-range.

Comment: @j.c there's no null pointer exception in the logs.I have posted the whole logcat

Comment: When you convert with `Imgproc.cvtColor` i think you need to pass two Mats, because RGBA and GRAY have different dimensions.

Comment: SIGSEGV is a Segmentation Faults, it means you addressed some unallocated memory - OpenCV core is native C++ code, the log messages are different from the ones you usually get with java.

Comment: @j.c well if you say so then i'll try something else with the code,and let you know if it worked